# PHPCS Plugin for Sublime Text 3 gives WinError 2

Tags: php, sublimetext3

I installed the PHPCS plugin for Sublime Text 3 and setup the user configuration file as follows:

```
{

// Path to php on windows installation
// This is needed as we cannot run phars on windows, so we run it through php
"phpcs_php_prefix_path": "C:\\wamp\bin\\php\\php5.4.12\\php.exe",

// This is the path to the bat file when we installed PHP_CodeSniffer
"phpcs_executable_path": "C:\\wamp\\bin\\php\\php5.4.12\\phpcs.bat",

// PHP-CS-Fixer settings
// Don't want to auto fix issue with php-cs-fixer
"php_cs_fixer_on_save": false,

// Show the quick panel
"php_cs_fixer_show_quick_panel": true,

// The fixer phar file is stored here:
"php_cs_fixer_executable_path": "C:\\wamp\bin\\php\\php5.4.12\\php-cs-fixer.phar",

// PHP Linter settings
// Yes, lets lint the files
"phpcs_linter_run": true,

// And execute that on each file when saved (php only as per extensions_to_execute)
"phpcs_linter_command_on_save": true,

// Path to php
"phpcs_php_path": "C:\\wamp\bin\\php\\php5.4.12\\php.exe",

// This is the regex format of the errors
"phpcs_linter_regex": "(?P<message>.*) on line (?P<line>\\d+)",


// PHP Mess Detector settings
// Not turning on the mess detector here
"phpmd_run": false,
"phpmd_command_on_save": false,
"phpmd_executable_path": "",
"phpmd_additional_args": {}
}
```

When I try to sniff a PHP file I get the following error:
"FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"

I've double checked my paths and they are correct, is it possible Sublime is only reading the default configuration file and not the user configuration file?

EDIT - My paths were missing a second backslash, I apologize, sniffer is working now.

Answer (score 4):

I've tried with not reading any instructions and i found a solution. try these steps:

- Download php code sniffer addon via Package Control in ST3.
- Download The php-cs-fixer File From This Website => cs.sensiolabs.org/ (Direct Link => cs.sensiolabs.org/get/php-cs-fixer.phar)
- Copy Downloaded File To Your php.exe directory (mine is
  C:/XAMMP/php/php.exe)
- download PHP_CodeSniffer PEAR code package from this page pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer/download/All (Direct
  Link => http://download.pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer-1.5.0RC4.tgz)
- find
  PHP_CodeSniffer-1.5.0RC4.tgz\PHP_CodeSniffer-1.5.0RC4\scripts\phpcs.bat
  and copy this file too (in your php.exe directory)
- copy the first post's config file, change your directory accordingly while writing in
  Package Settings -> Php Code Sniffer -> Settings - User  File.
  This Method Worked For Me On Sublime Text 3 Build 3047 In Win8 x64 System... No more slow ST2 for me...
  Cheers